Merging DEM with different resolutions
I am going to merge two DEM raster files with different resolutions (5m and 12.5m). I would like to merge them in a way that they should keep their own resolution.
How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

You can't combine rasters and retain resolution. You have to choose one or the other. You could downsample to 2.5m and shift to retain content; with compression, the 25x increase in 12.5m's pixel count won't be too oppressive.

You would have to either standardize the resolution to merge the two or you could choose to create a mosaic dataset with the two raster files.
The merge function would allow you to treat both raster files as a single item for additional edits and calculations whereas creating a mosaic dataset would allow you to keep the varying resolutions and create a combined image with the two raster files. A mosaic dataset can be treated more like an image where the pieces are fit together like a puzzle, while a merged dataset is more like a single new raster layer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
